# How to combine two tflite models into a single tflite model to run in it on android?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

we are working on an android application for detecting objects and face recognition in a single camera view and we are using Tensorflow API for implement both functionality, now we have a application that detects objects in real time via camera in which we used detect.tflite file and labelmap.txt file and we want to used another tflite model to detect faces in a single code. For this purpose, we decided to combine two tflite model into a single model to perform both operation with single camera view. Please guide us that how can we achieve this task to combine both models. Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Feed the same camera view to two interpreters. Never heard of combining two models to one!!

Comment: Okay Sir, Can you please provide some resources for that how can we feed the same camera view to two interpreters?

Comment: If you have already succeeded in detecting objects, then use the same bitmap and pass is to the interpreter or the face detector class. There are no resources...you will maybe do it for the first time